# How much weight $w$ is needed to keep the lever balanced?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque

[image: 1]

Imagine here's a strange lever

- on the right side, there's weight $W$ sitting on an arm with the
  length $L$
- on the left side, there's the L shape thing attached to the end, marked as blue in the picture, and a weight $w$ is placed in the middle, ie, the distance from the fulcrum is $L/2$

How much weight $w$ is needed to keep the lever balanced?

At the first glace, it seems $w = 2W$, as the law of lever says $w * L/2 = W L$.

But then I'm confused looking at the blue part

- the blue part is balanced, so the force pressing down from weight $w$, shall equals to the force from the main part of the lever's left arm (in black) pushing it up, hence $w$
- so the force from the blue part pressing the main part of the lever's left arm, is also $w$
- by law of lever, only considering the main part of the lever, we have $w L = W L$, or $w = W$.

Please enlighten me where I stumble?

Answer (score -2):

It would appear that the “blue part” is rigidly attached at the left end and does not otherwise touch the lever.  I will assume that it has a weight (w) and that the vertical segment is negligible. Then the weight of the blue part acts at its center of gravity, and you have two CCW torques: w(L/2) and w(3L/4).